# How to use `c-cpp-reference` on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, kdevelop

I just installed the `c-cpp-reference` after installing the `KDevelop`.

I see a lot of files are installed with `dpkg -L c-cpp-reference`. But how to use it? And preferably, in KDevelop.

Now I am using it through opening the url below directly in Firefox:

`/usr/share/doc/c-cpp-reference/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop can only read Qt help books (QCH). Or at least that's one way to make the cppreference content available to it.

Download the QCH from here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives#Qt_help_book

Then import in KDevelop via Settings -> KDevelop -> Qt Help